# MIME TYPE: Linking to CSS w/ a txt Extension

Tags: html, css, mime

```
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="./foo.css.txt" />
```

**Firbug Error**

---

The stylesheet foo.css.txt was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/plain", is not "text/css".

**Explanation**

---

The browser is interpreting the CSS as a text document rather than a CSS, despite any effort to force it's MIME through the browser.  Naturally, in production I will be using `foo.css` (w/o the txt extension), but I would think this would be possible.  It works for JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js.txt"></script>
```

**Other Thoughts**

---

- Setting `type="css"` doesn't show an error in Firebug and the page validates, but the CSS doesn't load properly - I'm pretty sure that's not a valid MIME type though.  I tried to find a list of MIME types off W3C, but as with everything it's difficult to find/understand W3C
- This does work with other, less popular, extensions such as dat: `href="./foo.css.dat"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the `type` attribute in HTML you are saying "When you fetch this resource, *expect* to get this type of data." This allows user agents (such as browsers) to avoid requesting resources that they know they can't handle. For CSS you need to set this to `text/css`.

When the server responds to the request, the HTTP `Content-Type` header says "This content **is** of this type". It is canonical and must also be set to `text/css` for CSS data.

Because you have used a .txt file, the server (in a default configuration) says that the file contains data that is `text/plain` so it tells the browser that. You cannot override this from the browser.

> It works for JavaScript

Browsers, for various reasons, tend to ignore the Content-Type specified by servers for JavaScript. This could be considered a bug in those browsers.

> Setting type="css" doesn't show an error in Firebug and the page validates, but the CSS doesn't load properly - I'm pretty sure that's not a valid MIME type though

`css` is not a registered MIME type, the browser doesn't recognise it as a stylesheet language that it can understand, so it doesn't event try to download it.

> I tried to find a list of MIME types off W3C, but as with everything it's difficult to find/understand W3C

The W3C isn't responsible for the MIME type registry, which you can find at http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/

Comment: I think the real question, which I failed to include, is: `is it possible to get this to work in the HTML page`  I'm fairly certain I've modified the content-type in Apache for txt files in the past, but I want to see if there's a quick and easy way to add something to the "link" element.  -- I'm going to test what happens when dynamically loading CSS files w/ JavaScript too.

Comment: No, there isn't anything quick and easy you can add to the link element, as I said: "You cannot override this from the browser."

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone still wants to do this, it can be done with JavaScript. Here's a rough jQuery solution:

```
var sheet = $('<style></style>')
$('head').append(sheet)
sheet.load("./foo.css.txt")
```

Comment: Interesting example - retrieve the file as text and build the STYLE element around it.  It's been a while, but I think the reason I was doing this was to quickly debug/browse js/css files w/o changing any OS file type association.  That way the OS might still execute a `js` file, but would open a `js.txt` in something like notepad.  The CSS was probably for consistency.

Comment: Follow-up: my comment (from years ago) doesn’t do any justice to propping up this answer, which would circumvent the issue. +1 for a creative approach

Answer (score 0):

If you could use .php instead of .txt you could set type from within the file itself.

Comment: (see the comment I left for RDL)

Comment: Okay. The only other way I can think of is changing the handling of files via Apache, but you state you want to stay away from that.

Comment: Yes, to stay away from any special configuration for txt files :)  This is merely an exercise not a production case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a server side extension like .php

In this case you can set the mime-type in the document itself.

Comment: This isn't to get it to get something to work, this is to get it to work with ".txt" w/o changing the server config.